# Async await promised data not available at express POST call

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to asynchronous programming and trying to get my head around the following:

The code following //DB Load Users works fine
The code following //New user to DB does write a new user to mysql DB, but fails to refresh the data in user prior to rendering.
The webserver hangs (cursor timer symbol) and when I reenter the url the page renders, but without the new data. Only restarting the terminal makes the data available on the webpage.

```
//DB Load Users
const users = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var sql = "SELECT username, useremail, userage, useruniqueid FROM users";
    db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        resolve(result);
    });
})

//DB refresh Users
function refresh() {
    const users = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var sql = "SELECT username, useremail, userage, useruniqueid FROM users";
        db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            resolve(result);
        });
    })
}


//Render (express) HTML with promise resolve after DB-query - works!!
app.get("/", async(_req, res, next) => {
    try {
        res.render("home", { data: await users });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});



//New user to DB
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const inputUserName = req.body.username
    const inputUserEmail = req.body.useremail
    const inputUserAge = req.body.userage
    const inputUserUniqueId = req.body.useruniqueid

    db.query('insert into users values(?,?,?,?)', [inputUserUniqueId, inputUserName, inputUserEmail, inputUserAge], (err, result) => {
        if (err) { console.log(err) } else {
            console.log('new user added');
        }
    })
    refresh(); //update users from DB
    // wait for user-data and render webpage - does not work - no updated data and webserver hangs
    app.get("/", async(_req, res, next) => {
        try {
            res.render("home", { data: await users });
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    });
})
```

I had the webserver side fully operational when I worked with a manually defined users [], pushing new entries to the end of the array. So I am assuming it is my lack of understanding the async timing here.

Comment: What sql library for node are you using? Is this how the callback should be formed? Have you tried doing `users.then( console.log )` on startup to see if it ever resolves? How are you creating your `db` object? Are you only querying after you received a pool of connections? Also, your `users`  will never be refreshed, since you define it as a constant, _and_ when you reload them it is a new constant scoped to the refresh method.

Comment: TYSM. This has solved the data issue. The new user is now showing up after reentering the url of the webserver manually.

The issue that remains is the hanging webserver. The cursor is cycling untill I reenter the url (refreshing would probably resend the user entry).

Comment: This is only day 4 of my Node-js life :). I have already seen that the mysql 2 module is recommended, but am currently still using the standard mysql module. It is on my improvement list.

Comment: The module is not the issue, the scoping was, and scopes can be hard to debug if you don't know what to look for yet. Did my answer help or was it the comment?

Comment: That was my impression too. It was the answer TYSM. I just don't want to close the question yet, as the issue with the webserver is still open.

Comment: Hold on, the other answer was right about something else though, and I missed it! @LawrenceCherone The issue is that you are only register the `get /` route _after_ a `post` route has been called. Obviously, your page will hang until an initial post is completed then. I will amend my answer, but would be happy to give Luke the opportunity to answer it and get credit :)

Comment: I was confused. There was another answer but then it disappeared.

Comment: I know, it was removed by the author because of an Oopsie (it was by the user I tagged in my comment). He did point out the structural issue, but I didn't catch that and focused on the oopsie. My bad. I have amended my answer with the next bit, but credit goes to @LawrenceCherone . I also called him Luke. My brain is farting all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your scoping: `const users` *cannot be changed* (hence: constant) and even when you try to, you scope it to the `refresh` function, which means it won't get updated, even if your query runs correctly. Here's code that should work as expected:

```js
// Make users replacable by using `let`, which can be changed.
let users = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var sql = "SELECT username, useremail, userage, useruniqueid FROM users";
    db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        resolve(result);
    });
})

function refresh() {
   // You want to assign this new promise to the global `users` variable.
   // If you set a constant here, the result will only be
   // available within this function scope.
   // But because the global object is `let`, we can reassign it from within here.
   // Just don't _declare_ it here, only reassign it.
   users = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var sql = "SELECT username, useremail, userage, useruniqueid FROM users";
        db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            resolve(result);
        });
    })
}
```

There is a second issue, however. The way your code is structured has a couple of issues. First of, since there's no final callback, you will *never* return a non-existing route. You might want to do this somewhat like this at the *end* of your code:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   
    res.status(404).send( "This page does not exists" );

})
```

The above code will output a 404 page if the server finds no capable method that can handle the request.

Now the reason it hangs is because you *only* register your `get /` route *inside* the callback of your `post /` route. So unless a `post` call is completed, the `get` route is unavailable. Simply register it outside of the post response:

```js
app.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
    const inputUserName = req.body.username
    const inputUserEmail = req.body.useremail
    const inputUserAge = req.body.userage
    const inputUserUniqueId = req.body.useruniqueid

    db.query('insert into users values(?,?,?,?)', [inputUserUniqueId, inputUserName, inputUserEmail, inputUserAge], (err, result) => {
        if (err) { console.log(err) } else {
            console.log('new user added');
        }
    });

    refresh(); //update users from DB
    res.render("home", { data: await users });

});

app.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
        res.render("home", { data: await users });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }

});
```

Your final `next(err)` is not doing anything - there is *nothing next*, so your server will hang, as there is no response being sent back. Usually until the timeout occurs.

Comment: Hello and TYSM. But this breaks the code (the res.render in the post route), as await can only be called in async functions and I have to wait for the promise or the current state of users will break the code.

Comment: Ah yes. Just add ‘async’ before the method. I will adjust my post when I get the chance. Express doesnt care if anythings async, it only cares the response is filled and sent _at some point_

Comment: With great pride I declare that I just found the solution to this bit myself haha :) But thank you so much for the other 99.999 % !!

Comment: No issue! It’s much more satisfying if you find it yourself! Happy coding, keep going. This will all come naturally once the flow is etched in your mind. Cheers!